# How can I resolve the error "Net wire X has multiple names"?

Tags: altium

The message "Nets Wire AHS2 has multiple names" is shown as a warning in Altium.

How can I solve this please? I spent more than two hours and I couldn't locate the problem.

PS: I know it is a warning but I want to make it disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you look a bit closer, the two nets are in fact joined (you can see the junction)
[image: Closeup of net junctions]

The only ways to get rid of the warning are:

1. If you did *not* intend to tie those nets together, remove the offending junction and check the schematic.
2. If you *did* intend to tie the two nets, either delete one of the net names or use a net tie (I would simply delete one of the net names).

The warning is there because in the layout tool, *only one of the net names can appear*.

You could adjust your warnings, but that is not usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The net has multiple names. Remove names from that net so that it only has one name.

From the image provided it looks like you can just remove the name AHS2 without any issues. Clearly you need to make sure that nothing is looking for the net name AHS2, but we can't do that for you.