# CircuitMaker: Nets Wire JACK_IN_GND has multiple names, why is this bad?

Tags: circuit-design, pins, circuitmaker

[image]

There is a solution here: [How can I resolve the error "Net wire X has multiple names"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434047/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-net-wire-x-has-multiple-names)

However, JACK_IN_GND and JACK_OUT_GND will go to two different directions (one input cable and one output cable). And GNDs should be tied together.

Why is having two names so bad? Should I simply call it GND? And assuming since it's next to another wire (JACK_IN_SIGNAL and JACK_OUT_SIGNAL) that it is a GND signal for IN resp. OUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple nets with different names would seem to indicate an accidental short in your schematic design entry. It could also be confusing if you are reading a schematic. Some PCB software won't allow it at all, requiring all connected signals to be named the same thing.

If the pins are intended to both be connected to ground, simply connect both directly to ground rather than giving them intermediate names.

If your purpose for wanting to use the net name to help you work out which pin is which on a header, you are better off using text labels for that. Name the net based on what it is connecting to (GND), and add text next to the header to provide extra info on where the pins are to go off-board.

Comment: Thanks, yes in this case I could easily put the GND symbol directly to the connector. And otherwise I will use text labels in future.